# Copying a 2d character array int another 2d character array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, 2d, charat

I am trying to copy a 2d character array into another 2d character array via a constructor  of a class. The original array is read in from a an external text file and then converted into a 2d array. However I can't seem to read in this 2d array from another class. The code that I am trying is listed below, it is the constructor of the search class. Thank You.

```
char[][] arraytwo;

public search(char[][] inarray)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < inarray.length; i++)
    {
        String row = inarray.;
        for(int j = 0; j < inarray[i].length; j++)
        {
            arraytwo[i][j] = inarray.charAt(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement inside your inner for loop should be:

```
arraytwo[i][j] = inarray[i][j];
```

You index an array using the same syntax whether you're reading from it or writing to it. (`charAt` is a method you'd call on a `String`, not an array.)

---

Also, you don't need the line

```
String row = inarray.;
```

There's a syntax error on that line anyway.

Comment: thank you for the response, sorry about the syntax error. However when I call the array to be printed in another method I get a java.lang.NullPointerException error, am I missing something?

Comment: @Tyler Oh yeah, you need to create a new array for `arraytwo`. The dimensions should be the same size as `inarray`.

Comment: so I have my arraytwo that should be populated with the characters from the external text file that have been read into inarray from the array in the other class(Driver). I now need to set arraytwo equal to another array and then call that array, if so do I need to loop through again to populated the third array?

Comment: @Tyler No, you don't need a third array. You just need to create a new array (using the `new` keyword) for `arraytwo`. You've declared a reference for `arraytwo`, but you haven't created an object.

Answer (score 0):

the code is malformed, you copied that wrong:

```
String row = inarray.;
```